# I can't save my Stack Exchange account in Firefox

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

OK, I hope this is not the one million and first question about this problem :) I didn't find any similar question.

I have a **Stack Exchange** account, and when I try to sign in to it, Firefox doesn't suggest saving my account and password. It seems is because of that log in the page's properties.

Is there any solution?

**Edit:**
It works correctly with other sites, and I am logged in while have not deleted the cookies, but when I delete the cookies and try to log in, there is no suggestion because Firefox has not saved anything.

Briefly when I enter my username and password, I want my browser to ask me "Remember this account?" like other sites do.

Comment: Doesn't the site remember your login through cookies + HTML 5 local storage? Any idea what's wrong with the form - any other pages not work for you?

Comment: @Rup: I edited it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Auto complete is disabled on StackID forms.  You can find the relevant code [here](http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Views/AffiliateForms/LoginIFrame.cshtml#14).</s>

This is a workaround for browsers not exposing a way to detect when a field has been auto-completed.  This tends to smash our field overlays, greatly confusing users.

I'm field testing a (really unpleasant) work around for this auto-complete nonsense browsers have.  All major browsers should now offer to save credentials entered into Stack Exchange sites.